# How to Import Entities and Intents to LUIS in bulk?

Tags: azure-language-understanding, watson-conversation

I'm trying to migrate a watson app to LUIS, or at least it's intents and entities, I have it currently exported as a json file, is there any way to import intents and entities in bulk to LUIS? I know you can import values for each individual entity but how can I import many at the same time?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this in the LUIS website. You can either modify your JSON, then import the JSON as an app, or you add use the REST API to add the intents, entities, and utterances to an existing app.

My preference is to generate the LUIS JSON app definition from the watson app definition.

Comment: I just finished making a script that translate the Watson JSON to a LUIS JSON, the problem is that when I try to import it I get the error: Closedlists count cannot exceed the limit 50, any workarounds to this?